# I want to rename files automatically with PHP

Tags: php, html

I want the code to automatically rename the file. So, if the file name is image.png, and another user uploads a file called image.png, the code will automatically rename the file to image1.png, and so on.

My current code doesnt upload the picture. The page goes blank and says: "File is an image - image/png.".

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image. ";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Checks if file already exists, and if it does, it should rename it.

    while (!file_exists($target_file.".".$imageFileType)) {
        $target_file = $target_file.$i++;
        $uploadOk = 1;
    }

    // Checks file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large. ";
        $uploadOk = 0;

        // Only allow specific file types
        if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed, your uploaded a $imageFileType file. ";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Checks if $uploadOk is set to 0 by mistake.
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded. ";

        // All is ok
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I was expecting the code would use $target_file and add $i++. I was expecting that it would keep incrementing the number until there is no file with the same name as it on the server.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `while(file_exists(...))` instead of `while(!file_exists(...))`?  You want to go inside that block if the file _does_ already exist, right?  Also, you probably don't really want to be appending a number every time (1, then 12, then 123) which is what you would be doing right now.

Comment: It looks like you have a syntax error. At least I got an error in my IDE when I copied the code in. Maybe you have not pasted the full code here.

Comment: Is this the whole code snippet?  If so you are missing quite a lot of logic. eg. file_exists($target_file.".".$imageFileType) - these 2 variables are not being set anywhere.  If there is more code then its good to post it all so we can help.

Comment: I would check your `if else` braces, you are missing one end `}`.

Comment: Also, you're trying to move the uploaded file in an if-statement that only runs if the file is too large, which makes zero sense. The check `if ($uploadOk == 0)` is also pointless where it currently is located, since you set that variable to `0` before that check, inside the if-statement.

Comment: There is something wrong with your WHILE loop and the scope of your IF-size>500000000, let's consider the documentation : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: One more thing. If `$check` is false, you set `$uploadOk` to `0`. Then, in your while-loop, that variable will be set to `1` every time (unless there already is a file with that exact name?). There are too many logical errors in this code.